# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Im tring to add nivo slider to my wordpress site and i get that weird exception : 
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider' 
my website address is: http://www.ourevent.co.il/ 
(it's in hebrew so you may not understand) - but the slider should show up at the top of the content area and he isn't.

i check that jquery is included and it's not called twice, 
can someone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: It can only be one of two things, and you've mentioned both of them in your question already. (well, three, the third being `$.noConflict(true)` being used before including the plugin)

Comment: `"I'm trying to add..."` and how exactly is that? Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the nivoslider.js file? By the looks of it you have included a different slider plugin called jquery.slimscroll.min.js?

You will need to include your nivoslider.js file after you jquery file and then make sure you wrap you .`nivoSlider` call in a `$(document).ready()`

Comment: it's included,
still now working.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: yes,
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jcarousel' custom.js:88
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'

Comment: There is no reference to any nivoSlider plugins on that site.